# Issues with validation when updating whole objects with PUT requests

Tags: laravel, api, rest, patch, put

We're working on a project management web app with a back-end in Laravel and a front-end in Angular.

My colleague, who works with Angular, prefers to send me whole instances of objects when updating them, because it's easier for him. I know it's a standard scenario for PUT requests, i.e., replacing an old object with a new one.

I wasn't fully aware of that when starting to work on the REST API in Laravel, so my PUT routes work similarly to PATCH - one can supply either of all of the fields and each of them is validated separately.

The problem came when working on tasks assigned to users.

We don't allow to create tasks that start and/or end before the current date and time. To implement that and other similar constraints, I've written a lot of validation code in the controller, which is run during both creation of an object and updating it (with other methods and documentation comments, the task controller got to around 1000 lines).

Since I validate each field again when I receive them through PUT, and to complete the task you have to update it and switch its "done" property to true, the start and end dates are also compared against the current date and time - which, because the task was created sometime in the past, results in an error and update fails.

To combat this I thought of creating another function to check the object from the request for any changes and skip the fields that have the same value, but:

- that would make the routes even more sluggish than these already are;
- I'm more than sure that there is a much smarter way to go about this.

My questions are:

1. How should I solve the issue, i.e., how to structure a safe PUT route in the given task scenario that won't be sluggish to validate, overly complex and won't violate the app design constraints? For sure it shouldn't be left to the front-end to check data integrity.
2. What is the *proper* way to validate interdependent data in Laravel? I think that my code is way too complex and long for something as simple as tasks, especially when I haven't added any roles and companies yet. I already use the built-in validator, but I don't know how to use it properly with fully interdependent data, except for writing lots of code to modify the validation rules based on the request. I've also already put validation rules to the task model, so that the code repeats itself less, but it's still horrendous.

Comment: *"that would make the routes even more sluggish than these already are;"* - is it? adding function call might add stuff to the stack, but its not necessarily slower. fyi, laravel resource controller handles both put and patch on `update` function while new items on via post on `store`. your question feels very broad - i'm not quite sure what 1000 lines validation do.

Comment: @BagusTesa yes, I use Laravel resource controller to create these routes. By 1000 lines I meant that the task controller, which includes all of the methods, their validation and documentation, is that long, and I *suppose* it's a lot when considering that I have many more features to add there, like checking permissions

Comment: My main question relates to the update request. I want the current PUT route to accept the whole task object and work properly. Now it accepts any combination of fields and it validates them separately. That's an issue, because if someone updates only, for instance, the title of a task that was supposed to start and end before the current date and time, then the update will fail, because the object from the request will contain dates from the past, which are unacceptable for the validator.

Comment: During task creation, I check whether:
- all of the fields are of the required type,
- start date/time are later than the current time
- there is a start date/time when you want to add an end date/time
- end date/time are later than the start date/time
- the task is assigned to an existing user
- if the task has parent task, that the parent task exists
- and much more concerning the automatic creation of a cyclic (regularly repeating) task

Comment: i noticed some items you can improve on here. for instance, depends on the requirement you can use middlewares to handle the permission checks. also, remember, you can make optional fields in laravel - of which will only validate if the field actually sent to the controller. but again, wall of text with no code is not a [mcve] - your question is again, too broad.